How to solve $\int\frac{e^{x/2}\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{3\cos x+4\sin x}}dx$?
How do I solve the integral: $\int\frac{e^{x/2}\cos x}{\sqrt[3]{3\cos x+4\sin x}}dx$.
It was a question from the graduation prank at my school. I found it interesting and tried like substituting the third root in the denominator but it didn't work out. My second try was to think from the answer that WolframAlpha provided : $\frac{6}{25}e^{x/2}\sqrt[3]{(3\cos x+4\sin x)^2} +C$ , because $\frac{6}{25} = \frac{2}{5}*\frac{3}{5}$ and tried that the inside of the third root was substituted because $\sqrt[3]{u^2}$ integrates to $\frac{3u\sqrt[3]{u^2}}{5}$. But than I had no idea.

One thing that stands out to me is the coefficients of $sinx$ and $cosx$ in the denominator, as they are both integer side lengths of a right triangle. What this means is that there exists a value $\theta$ such that $sin\theta=\frac45$ and $cos\theta=\frac35$. Solving for three and four in each of those equations and substituting the resulting expressions into our integrand yields the following integral after a little simplification involving trig
$$\frac{1}{5^{1/3}}\int\frac{e^{x/2}cos}{\sqrt[3]{cos(x-\theta)}}dx$$
Not sure if this will work, but it is something worth trying

@math-physicist I don't believe you differentiated it correctly.

Hint: $\frac d {dx} x(4\sin(2\log x) + 3\cos(2\log x))^{2/3} = \frac{25\cos(2 \log x)}{3 \sqrt[3]{4\sin(2 \log x) + 3\cos(2 \log x)}}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \quad  \int \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}} \cos x}{\sqrt[3]{3 \cos x+4 \sin x}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{25} \int \frac{e^{\frac{x}{2}}[3(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)+4(-3 \sin x+4 \cos x)]}{\sqrt[3]{3 \cos x+4 \sin x}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{25}\left[3 \int e^{\frac{x}{2}}(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac{2}{3}} d x+6 \int e^{\frac{x}{2}} d(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac 23}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{25}\left[3 \int e^{\frac{x}{2}}(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac{2}{3}} d x+6 e^{\frac{x}{2}}(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac{2}{3}}-3 \int e^{\frac{x}{2}}(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac{2}{3}} d x\right] \\
& =\frac{6}{25} e^{\frac{x}{2}}(3 \cos x+4 \sin x)^{\frac{2}{3}}+C
\end{aligned}
$$
